# Getting issue with creation of Firefox profile with Selenium 3.4/3.5/3.6

Tags: selenium

I tried with the below code. I am unable to import the `FirefoxProfile` package to my IDE.

```
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile myProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("SeleniumTest");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so please edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("SeleniumTest");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(myProfile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: This should nail the OP.